# Can you place two edit fields side-by-side?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In all the examples I've seen it's just one element per line. I would like to place 2 or more edit boxes next to each other to conserve vertical space. Has anyone run across sample showing how this is done?

Answer (score 3):

That's not common in most application (due to limited screen size) but you should be able to do something like this using the `UIViewElement`. E.g.

Define your own `UIView` type (e.g. `MyView`) that contains the two (or more) UI elements you want (e.g. two `UITextView`).

```
// incomplete example
class MyView : UIView {

   public UIView (string first, string second)
   {
       tv1 = new UITextView (new RectangleF (...)) { Text = first; }
       tv2 = new UITextView (new RectangleF (...)) { Text = second; }
   }

   // ...
}
```

Next create the `UIViewElement` and add them to your `DialogViewController`.

```
new UIViewElement ("caption", new MyView ("a", "b"), false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've decided to use separate lines for each Entry Element, but I'm sure I can use this technique later. Thanks for the reply.